# Is it possible to redirect to a webpage if a value is a certain number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my website checking another website for a value, and returning back with the results. I'm trying to get my page to redirect me, if I have a certain value.

Is this possible?

Here is my code. `

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/2fd6657d79448494/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {
  var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
  var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
  alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
  }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: We are going to need a little bit more information in order to help you with this. Are you checking another third party website for that value or are you checking your own site for that value?

Comment: You should specify the langage and the reason you have to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the value inside the success function of an AJAX function, there use `window.location = "http://www.example.com"` to do a javascript redirect.

In this example if temp is > 80 then the redirect happens!! (which is at the time of writing this post!!). The code runner below will show 404 or server error because `example.com` is not a valid page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/2fd6657d79448494/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(parsed_json) {
      var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
      var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f'];
      alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f);
      if (temp_f > 80) {
        window.location = "www.example.com";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but replacing the temperature string seems to break the redirect. Not sure what the cause of this is, could you perhaps help me troubleshoot? Tried multiple different strings. None work.

Comment: what did u replace with?

Comment: I've tried "weather" and "feelslike_f".   Edit: It seems like only weather doesn't work. I mistyped a space in feelslike_f.

Comment: Figured it out. Overcast required you to put a space in between it. Also, is it possible to make it so that instead of having one number to redirect, multiple? For example, I don't want 98 to redirect, I want 98, 97, 96, 95 ect.

Comment: use `if(temp==98 || temp==97)`